# CSS borders problems

Tags: html, css

Im currently trying to make a square with 4 small squares inside, and I have been having troubles with a way I was trying to do.
So this is the code:

```css
#grandbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 204px;
  height: 204px;
  border: solid thin black;
  left: 40%;
  top: 8%;
}
div.smallbox {
  border: solid thin black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandbox">
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
</div>
```

I wanted to make the css style of the borders:

```
border: 2px solid black
```

But if I do that the boxes just break out of the bigger box and are display vertically.

I'm pretty newbie with this, as I currently started my carreer, but I cannot understand why doesn't it work.

PS: Sorry if bad english, not my first language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, border widths are added to the given width. With the `box-sizing: border-box;` rule, you can include the border into the width, so that you have no break anymore. See this snippet:

```css
#grandbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid thin black;
  left: 40%;
  top: 8%;
}
div.smallbox {
  border: solid thin black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandbox">
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
  <div class="smallbox"></div>
</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing for more information about box-sizing.

Comment: So, i wasn't telling the browser how to size it? Thank you for explaining this!

Comment: You weren't telling the browser to include the border into your width instruction. Thatswhy the `.smallbox` elements were greater than 100px because of their border width.

Comment: Browsers use _by default_ the standard box model. With `box-sizing: border-box` you tell it to switch to an equivalent of IE6 box model which was highly despised and _cough cough_ way better actually. Very good summary at https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ (you don't need box-sizing on pseudos IMHO but apart from that this Universal Box... is genius. You can mix a plugin which uses another box model whatever box model you're using)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: My answer is more of a hack solution. **The accepted answer** above that incorporates the box-sizing automatically including borders into the width is a better answer.

In your original calculation of height and width (204) I don't think you were accounting for both sides of each square being an additional 4 pixels larger.

Adjusting the width and height to 208px should solve your problem.

```css
#grandbox
    {
        position: absolute;
        width:208px;
        height:208px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        left:40%;
        top: 8%;
    }

div.smallbox
    {
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
        line-height: 100px;

    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="grandbox">
    <div class="smallbox">

    </div>
    
    <div class="smallbox">

    </div> 
    
    <div class="smallbox">

    </div>
    
    <div class="smallbox">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The outer box should be positioned `relative` and the four inside boxes `absolute`. Then you just need to position them using `left` `right` `top` `bottom` properties.

```css
#grandbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 204px;
  height: 204px;
  border: solid thin black;
  left: 40%;
  top: 8%;
}
div.smallbox {
  border: solid thin black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100px;
}
div.sb1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div.sb2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
div.sb3 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
div.sb4 {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandbox">
  <div class="smallbox sb1">

  </div>
  <div class="smallbox sb2">

  </div>
  <div class="smallbox sb3">

  </div>
  <div class="smallbox sb4">

  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tivedem/edit?html,css,output) version.